# Changing WordPress website theme that is built with Elementor

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

Can we change WordPress website theme that is built with Elementor ?
I am new to WordPres and Elementor and I need to change the theme of website. Website is built with Elementor.
I have downloaded WordPress theme . Do I need to use the "Appearance -> Theme " option ?
Please help !

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have pages built with Elementor, it won't affect the design itself, It is a good practice to use Elementor Hello Theme as it is a light and "empty" theme you can customize things on top of it.